# Javascript creating hubs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server setup that is handling all of my routing and session stuff. I want the system to work so that when a user is logged in they are able to connect to a "hub" like entity that is uniquely based on the location of the "hub". I thought about working it like each of the "hubs" is a collection in a database, but the way it works is that a user connects to the "hub" and then disconnects from it when they are done but can connect to different "hubs" based on a location. How should I go about creating a unique group of "hub" like things that all act as objects with storable data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting to a "hub", why not just present them with different information from a database based on their location. The user will never really connect to anything other than your single backend. Unless, ofcourse, you set up different servers all over the world (known as a CDN, and probably a bit too much effort).

If you're using express, you could use something like mongodb for data storage.

With [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/) you get the [mongoose npm package](http://mongoosejs.com/). With that, you can create [Schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). You could have different Schemas as "hubs" and load the correct ones based on location data. That would let the user see different information for different locations.

Comment: i have been using mongodb for my user information, but can i make many different schemas or wouldnt that cause me to have a large amount of collections with a lot of space being used for it? My intentions are also to have the "hubs" interacting with the user while they are "connected" but not technically connected, depending on what the user is doing.

Comment: @strauss002 If the information stored in your hubs is largely the same, then you could just have one Schema, with a field denoting which hub it should be from. If it's not at all the same, then different Schemas would be the way to go.